# How to get the portion of image that is masked in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I have used CAShapeLayer for masking my image and i want to retrieve only the portion that i have masked.
When i retrieve, i am getting only the full image.

Can anyone please provide me some code/information regarding this ?

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

```
 maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, clippingPath.bounds.size.width, clippingPath.bounds.size.height) ; 
 maskLayer.path = [clippingPath CGPath];
 maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
 maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];


 [ imgView removeFromSuperview ] ;
 imgView.layer.mask = maskLayer ;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

A `CALayer` is for display only, it is not actually modifying the image itself.

To mask an image you'll have to create that yourself, either using Quartz 2D drawing or using `CIFilter`/`CIImage` from the CoreImage framework.

To mask an image using Core Graphics (Quartz 2D) use [`CGImageCreateWithMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithMask) and [`CGImageMaskCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageMaskCreate). These functions allow you to mask one image with the contents of the other. You say you now use a bezier path to mask, so you would have to render that path into an image first to be able to mask your original image.

To mask an image using CoreImage take a look at the [`CIBlendWithMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithMask) filter.

Comment: thanks Joris. As of now, I have used Bezier path to get the points of the image that has to be shown. I did this with masking. How to do that with CGContext, can you please share me some sample code so that i could have a better idea.

Comment: thanks Joris. Will i be able to retrieve the image that is masked as a  separate image? For eg : The part of the image that is not visible should not be in the new image that is created, only the masked portion of image should be available in the new image. Whole new image only of the masked portion should be retrieved. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: that is exactly what both methods are able to do. for example see: http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049/how-to-mask-images-with-core-graphics-in-ios for a Core Graphics example using above functions.